# Taking the derivative of the complex conjugate/absolute value of an interpolating function

Tags: interpolation, complex

I have following code:

```
Ψ = Exp[-(0.1 x - 0.01 I)^2];
special = energy -> 0.00043 - 0.0000887 I;
in = FunctionInterpolation[Ψ, {x, 0, Pi/2}];
norm = 2 NIntegrate[Abs[in[x]]^2, {x, 0, Pi/2}];
Ψn[x_] := 1/Sqrt[norm] in[x];
Ψf[x_, t_] := Ψn[x] Exp[- I energy t] /. special
j[x_, t_] := -I/
   100 (Conjugate[Ψf[x, t]] (D[Ψf[a, t], a] /. 
       a -> x) - Ψf[x, t] Conjugate[(D[Ψf[a, t], a] /. a -> x)])

left[x_, t_] := (D[Abs[Ψf[u, c]]^2, c] /. {c -> t, u -> x}) + 
   D[j[b, t], b] /. b -> x
```

sorry that I do not know how to exchange Ψ with $\Psi$ in the code here.

In my real code $\Psi$ is a complex function consisting of more than $200$ pieces, I just replaced that with a complex gaussion to demonstrate the problem I have.

So I want to take a couple of derivatives of the interpolating function defined by $\Psi f[x,t]$ and then evalate the result for some specific $x$ and $t$ and the result should be a real number. But all I get is this:

```
left[0, 0]

(* -((
  I ((-0.00647977 - 
       8.70272*10^-9 I) + (0.00647847 + 8.70272*10^-9 I) Derivative[
       1][Conjugate][
       6.72255*10^-7 + 0.0020002 I] - (1.29422*10^-6 - 
        8.69957*10^-10 I) Derivative[1][Conjugate][1.0001 + 0. I]))/(
  70 Sqrt[10])) - (0.0000573985 + 0.000278257 I) Derivative[1][Re][
   0. + 0. I]*)
```

I am aware of that mathematica assumes a complex $x$ and $t$ here when taking the derivative and that might be one of the reasons why it does not work. I guess `ComplexExpand[]` could solve a part of the problem but I do not exactly know how to use it here. Also (after playing around a bit) it seems that the `Conjugate[]` of the interpolating function creates another problem.
I would be very happy is someone could solve my issue :)

Comment: Your definition of `in` has an error: the upper bound for `x` is not any specific number, but rather an as-yet undefined symbol `r`.

Comment: What's `kbar` ??

Comment: oh man I should really test the code before I post it. sorry for that. kbar is just any real number. I replaced it with 100 in the code now.

Comment: For *your* code, from `left[0, 0]` I obtain much shorter output, namely, `0. + 0. I) - (0.0000564682 + 0.000273747 I) Derivative[1][Re][
   0. + 0. I]`.